# How to make ID map for hair cards using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

I'm using geometry nodes to make hair which I will bake down into a hair card texture. I will be converting the strands to a mesh using the curve to mesh node, and I want apply the curve ID as a unique greyscale value for each strand ID.

Comment: Just store your *Index* with the node `Store Named Attribute` in the attribute domain *Spline* before applying the node `Curve to Mesh`. This value will then be applied to each mesh island.